# Как в контроллере Spring узнать URL адрес откуда пришел запрос?

Tags: java, spring, mvc, url, controller

**Как в контроллере веб приложения Spring MVC узнать URL адрес страницы, от которой пришел запрос?**

```
@Controller
public class IssueController {
private DAOService issueService;    
@Autowired(required = true)
@Qualifier("issueService")
public void setIssueService(DAOService issueService) {
    this.issueService = issueService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "issues", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("issue", new Issue("Hello"));
    listsPreparation(model);
    return ".......";   /// здесь хотелось бы вернуться на страницу с которой был отправлен HTTP Запрос
}
```

Я понимаю, что так делать нельзя...

Понимаю и то, что запрос могут сформировать и напрямую, в адресной строке...

И то, что  этот URL можно передавать в качестве параметра для контроллера.

НО очень хочется узнать именно Best Practice для данной задачи.

Как красиво разрулить?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала нужно получить объект `HttpServletRequest` добавив его в параметры метода, а затем из него вытащить заголовок `referer`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "issues", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    model.addAttribute("issue", new Issue("Hello"));
    listsPreparation(model);
    return request.getHeader("referer");
}
```

Но ваш контроллер должен возвращать имя представления, а не адрес страницы. Для того чтобы переадресовать пользователя обратно, можно 
добавить `redirect:` к адресу

```
return "redirect:" + request.getHeader("referer");
```

Плюс добавить проверку: если он не указан, то открывать страницу по умолчанию.

Answer (score 4):

```
String referer = request.getHeader("referer");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping
public String getURL(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    model.addAttribute("URL", request.getRequestURL().toString());
    return model;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]